# Saving score/value in javascript not persistent

Tags: javascript, local-storage, save

I have created a little javascript game and the top 10 scores should save. They do while you have the game loaded but if the browser is refreshed the scores are cleared. how can I make it persistent?

This is what I have so far but it is still not working.

please bare in mind I am new to javascript.

```
function loadHighScores() {
  const highScoresJSON = localStorage.getItem("highScores");
  if (highScoresJSON !== null) {
    highScores = JSON.parse(highScoresJSON);
  } else {
    highScores = [];
  }
}

function displayHighScores() {
  topScores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
  const scoreListHTML = topScores
    .map((entry, index) => `${index + 1}. ${entry.initials} - ${entry.score}`)
    .join("<br>");
  scoreList.innerHTML = scoreListHTML;
}

function saveScore() {
  const initials = initialsElement.value.toUpperCase();
  if (initials.length === 3) {
    topScores.push({
      initials,
      score
    });
    topScores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
    topScores.splice(10);
    displayHighScores();
    resetGame();
    showStartScreen();
    initialsElement.value = "";

    // Save the high scores to local storage.
    localStorage.setItem("highScores", JSON.stringify(topScores));
  }
}
```

I would like the score to be saved permenently and only replaces if a higher score is achieved.

Comment: Your code looks ok, there must be some logic elsewhere. Probably you are calling saveScore in the moment where the scores are not loaded yet, and it would save empty array to localStorage, overriding the previous value.

Maybe you also want in the saveScore function to call loadHighScores first to be sure that you will not override it.

Comment: If `highScores ` doesn't exist in LocalStorage, you won't get `null`, you'll get `undefined`.